# Is there a similar relation to Robin's Inequality for the number of divisors ( $\sigma_0(n) $), instead of the sum of divisors (( $\sigma_1(n) $)

Tags: divisor-sum

Robin's Inequality states:

> $\sigma(n)\lt e^\gamma n\log\log n $

for any n>5040.

Is there an equivalent for $\sigma_0(n) $?